# Laravel 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Hello I have trouble with my database migrations in my laravel application

This is the error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL  
  : alter table `transactions` add constraint `transactions_user_sid_foreign`  
   foreign key (`user_sid`) references `users` (`sid`))
```

This is my transactions migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_sid')->index();
            $table->unsignedInteger('store_id')->index();
            $table->unsignedInteger('value');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

This is the users migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->unsignedInteger('role_id')->index();
            $table->string('sid')->unique();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

And finally my foreign keys:

```
Schema::table('transactions', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->foreign('user_sid')->references('sid')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('store_id')->references('id')->on('stores');
        });
```

Comment: What is the sequence of migration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add foreign key to a column with different type, so just change it, for example in `users` table:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('sid')->unique();
```